# Activity.java cross reference not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-source, eclipse-adt

I have imported the entire `AOSP` source code to `Eclipse` and I've been working with it for over 2 years now. All java classes are easily referenced to one another when I press F3 on a selected class. However, there is one exception, `Activity.java` is un-referencable.
That is even when I press F3 on private functions within the class, I am informed that "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor".
It is very annoying why this happens only for a certain class.
It is also very strange that ever since ICS the problem persists in **ALL** `AOSP` versions I have downloaded.

I haven't seen anyone else post about this issue.
How do I fix this?

Comment: is Activity in the classpath?

Comment: See my comment below. Other classes in the same directory work well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Folder

then tick your file which has Activity.java then press Ok

Comment: It does not explain why other classes in the same directory behave ok (have references from them)

Comment: Sometimes that directory doesn't include all files, I guessed so